# Throw NOT working

Tags: java, try-catch, throw

I have a piece of code that has driven me nuts. 
The general flow is that when a certain event in TRY occurs, I throw the exception... according to my understanding, whenever the `throw` is called, it simply stops further execution in the same class and return the control back from where this class's function was called...

Here is the code...

```
try{
    session = getHibernateSession();
    companyAccountLinkingWSBean = (CompanyAccountLinkingWSBean) wsAttribute
            .getBeanObject();

    companyToMatch = companyAccountLinkingWSBean.getCompanyCode();
    cnicToMatch = companyAccountLinkingWSBean.getCnic();

    LOG.debug("We have found the Mobile number from the WS Bean as input");

    mobile = companyAccountLinkingWSBean.getMobileNumber();
    LOG.info("Mobile is : " + mobile);
    if(mobile.isEmpty()){
        LOG.info("Coming in mobile.isEmpty()");
        companyResponceWSBean = new CompanyResponceWSBean();
        companyResponceWSBean.setpID(Constants.INPUT_MOBILE_ERROR);
        companyResponceWSBean.setMessage(Constants.INPUT_MOBILE_ERROR_MSG);
        companyResponceWSBean.setSuccess(false);
        response = new WSAttribute();
        response.setBeanObject(companyResponceWSBean);
        LOG.info("BEFORE THROWING");

        throw new PayboxFault(Constants.INPUT_MOBILE_ERROR, 
                Constants.INPUT_MOBILE_ERROR_MSG);
    }
    LOG.info("Out side IF statement!!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.info("IN Exception!!");
}
LOG.info("Out Side Exception . . . Before Returning ");
return response;
```

Output in LOG When Empty mobile field is given as input ...

> We have found the Mobile number from the WS Bean as input
>
> Mobile is :
>
> Coming in mobile.isEmpty()
>
> BEFORE THROWING
>
> IN Exception!!
>
> Out Side Exception . . . Before Returning

How is it actually possible?

Comment: You catch the exception so execution continues afterwards. That's what `catch` does.

Comment: Yes, i got the point. To break the execution, we have to return as mentioned below, Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Your understanding isn't quite correct. Catching an exception handles it, and after the `catch` is completed, flow will continue after the `try/catch`, unless you throw another exception, or re-throw the exception. This might explain it better:

```
try {
    // Happy case flow here ...
    throw new PayboxFault(...);
    // If an exception is thrown, the remainder of the `try` block is skipped
} catch (Exception e) {
    // The exception is now handled ...
    //  Unless a new exception is thrown, or the caught exception re-thrown
} finally {
   // Code here should always be called after the try OR catch block executes, 
   // Finally is called even if the catch re-throws
}
// Code after the try-catch-finally executes if the try completes successfully 
// OR if the exception is handled in the catch, but not if the catch re-throws
```

Comment: Thank you Stuart, comments in the code snippet helped me understanding try/catch flow alot. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

When you catch an exception, execution continues from after the `catch` block. If you don't want it to, you'll need to return from inside your catch (or not catch the exception at all and let it bubble up to the caller).

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    LOG.info("IN Exception!!");
    return null;
}
```

Or:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
    throw e; // rethrow exception.
}
```

Note that if you do this, the exception will continue to bubble up the call stack until you catch it somewhere else (such as in the calling method).

Comment: Thank you for the time and answer, it sort of worked out but I had my custom Exception, so i have to went the other way around. but surely your answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You are catching the Exception. So it will not transfer back the control to the calling function unless entire function is executed.

If you want to skip the

```
LOG.info("Out Side Exception . . . Before Returning ");
```

statement you can do

```
catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.info("IN Exception!!");
        throw e;
    }
```

And about

```
when ever the throw is called, it simply stops further execution in the same 
class and return the control back from where this class's function was called...
```

Yes only if you do not catch it. You catch an Exception if you intent to do something with it which includes logging it and rethrowing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time. additional explanation helped alot :)